# manually defining boolean conjunction

Tags: haskell, boolean, operators, pattern-matching

In [chapter 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals-Chapter-4-of-13) of Erik Meijer on Functional Programming Fundamentals, he essentially writes:

```
True  &&& x | x == True  = True
            | x == False = False
```

Isn't this unnecessarily verbose? Couldn't I just write:

```
True  &&& x = x
```

or even:

```
(&&&) True  = id

(&&&) False = const False
```

By the way, how come I cannot write the following?

```
(True  &&&) = id

(False &&&) = const False
```

ghci responds with:

```
Parse error in pattern: True &&&
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the way you define it is better.  From the Prelude:

```
True  && x = x
False && _ = False
```

You can only use sections in expressions, not in patterns.  There is no deep reason why `(True &&)` shouldn't be allowed in a pattern.  But it's such a rare thing to want that I don't think it's worth the complication.

Comment: N.B. I think you *can* write it as `(&&)` in a pattern. So `(&&) True = id` might work.

Comment: Yes, but (&&) isn't a section, but the prefix form of an infix operator, I think.

Comment: @Erik Hesselink yes, but there's no semantic difference between "a prefix operator" and "a double-sided section".  The language just allows one syntax when defining operators, and not the other.

Comment: `Carl`,the difference between a pattern and an expression is not a semantic difference. If you could write `(True &&) = id`, you could presumably write `True && = id`. It would involve subtler machinery for recognizing patterns, ie, making syntactic discriminations, no?